# Are [^\s] and \S equivalent in regular expressions?

Tags: regex

Are `[^\s]` and `\S` equivalent in canonic (widely accepted standards of) regular expressions? If not what is the difference?

(Both seem to match any non-whitespace character.)

Reason I ask: see `[^\s]` widely used even by seasoned regex writers and wonder why is that given `\S` is shorter and easier to read - for me at least.

Answer (score 1):

Both mean strictly the same: 1 non space character.

I don't know the reason why people doesn't use it, may be they are not aware of.